# Why is node.js not processing these both functions/methods asyncronousliy?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Why is node not processing the following both functions/methods asyncronousliy?

```
function loop(y) {
    var x = 1;
    for (let index = 0; index < y; index++) {
        x = x + index;
    }
    console.log(x);
}

loop(3000000000);
console.log(1);
```

Comment: Which "both functions" are you speaking of? `loop` and `console.log`? They are both sync why do you expect node to run em async?

Comment: Because that's not how Javascript or node.js works.  Javascript has a single thread of execution.  It runs a function until it returns and will not run the next function until the prior one has returned.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a function is `non-blocking` when:

1. current execution requests external service like I/O or networking requests etc.
2. a function call is put on a timer to be executed at a later time.

but your function is not any of those.

Comment: Thank you. How would I define an async function? `function asyncFunction(paramter, paramater, parameter, function callBackFunction() );` ?

Comment: @saitam Simply taking a callback doesn't make a function asynchronous. [read this](https://bytearcher.com/articles/does-taking-a-callback-make-a-function-asynchronous/)

Comment: Could you please post a link or some information how it works

Comment: Unfortunately the link doesn't explain how to define an async function by yourself. It just shows an example of an async function, which uses another async function

Answer (score 0):

You're not making any sort of asynchronous request in your current code. In node, code is *generally* executed in order unless specified otherwise.

Therefore, the loop finishes running first and then the last statement of your code is executed.